# window.open- title tag isn't shown in chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-chrome, title, window.open

I'm opening new window in javascript with window.open()

> window.open("UpdateEmailRemainder.aspx", "",
>   "width=630,height=500,status,resizable, top=" + top + ",left=" +
>   left);

in UpdateEmailRemainder.aspx.cs I set the title tag in server side code:

> this.Title = "Add Email Reminder";

however,the title still is "Untitled".
in ie works well.

update:
I

- try in HTML and still not working
- if you refresh the window several times, open the developer tool(f12) or open the page source- the title appeared.

Comment: sounds like a chrome bug. Its better to post this on chrome bug list.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the title in the `<title></title>` HTML.